# What is the relationship between flask, mongokit, pymongo, flask-pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongokit

I am really new to *Flask* and *MongoDB*. I read the Flask documentation about *MongoDB*, and turns out I felt so confused that I did not know which one I need to install.

In *Flask* document, it says if you want to operate *MongoDB*, you should install *Mongokit*, yes I did, I build the user structure like document said, and save it, but it did not work, I look up into MongoDB shell, nothing stored there.
So, i keep searching that I need *Pymongo*, and another document say that 
*Flask-PyMongo* is the bridge between MongoDB and Pymongo.

do I need to install all of them?
what's their relationship, I need someone clear my head a little bit
BTW, can I use *SQLalchemy*  with *MongoDB*? or I just use *Mongokit* whatever above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From  [MongoKit documentation](https://github.com/namlook/mongokit/wiki/Tutorial#getting-started-with-mongokit):

> MongoKit is based on pymongo. As such, all of the pymongo API is exposed through MongoKit. If you don't find what you want in the MongoKit API, please take a look at pymongo's documenation. All the pymongo API is exposed via connection, database and collection so Connection, Database and Collection are wrappers around pymongo objects.

MongoKit is an Object Document Mapper (ODM)

And as specify [here](http://namlook.github.io/mongokit/#)

> MongoKit is a python module that brings a structured schema and validation layer on top of the great pymongo driver.

As mentioned in [Flask-PyMongo documentation](http://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask-pymongo)

> Flask-PyMongo bridges Flask and PyMongo, so that you can use Flask’s normal mechanisms to configure and connect to MongoDB.

Now:

> Do I need to install all of them?

The answer is **NO** you can use either MongoKit or Flask-PyMongo

> Can I use SQLalchemy with Mongodb?

The answer is **NO** Why? [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261866/what-is-the-difference-between-an-orm-and-an-odm)