# Executing generic SQL in Java

Tags: java, mysql, generics

I'm working on a small web app that will use a MySQL DB, with several servlets doing different kinds of SQL - insert, update, delete, etc. Before, I used to write a separate class Database.java, with a separate function for each query. However, this builds up a large and messy file, and now I would like to make generic functions, such as this one:

```
    static ArrayList rs(String query, List params, int columns) {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        con = getConnection();          
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

        for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
            stmt.setObject(i+1, params.get(i));
        }

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            ArrayList thisRow = new ArrayList();

            for (int column = 1; column <= columns; column++) {
                thisRow.add(rs.getObject(column));

            }
            result.add(thisRow);

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    return result;

}
```

Is this good/bad, efficient/inefficient way of doing things? Are there better ways to achieve what I need? I've read something about "JPA", however, I have no understanding of how it works or is used, and would like the queries to be as generic as possible (typeless and with any number of parameters).

Comment: `close` calls should be in a `finally` block!

Comment: Looks very ugly, with another try-catch in the finally, but if that's the way to go, I'll change it, thanks

Comment: The JDBC API is as ugly as it gets...

Comment: Alternatively, you can use try-with-resources if you're using jre 1.7+ to close the connection upon going out of scope for the try-catch.

Answer (score 1):

very close, but to make it a bit more efficient, try doing this

```
static ArrayList rs(String query, List params, int columns) 
{
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    try (Connection con = getConnection())
    {
        try(PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) 
            {
                stmt.setObject(i+1, params.get(i));
            }
            try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery())
            {
                 while(rs.next()) 
                 {
                     ArrayList thisRow = new ArrayList();
                     for (int column = 1; column <= columns; column++) 
                     {
                          thisRow.add(rs.getObject(column));
                     }
                     result.add(thisRow);
                 }
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution could depend on the level of "generic" result you want to get. Anyway I recommend not to invent bicycles with plain JDBC API as it's too low-level.

In addition to JPA or MyBatis (which could seem to complex to start with) I think one of the easiest ways to go is to use [Spring JDBC template](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html). It provides [plenty of ways](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) to access data using SQL. The most trivial and generic example:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> queryResult = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("**qour sql select here**");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to come up with a more efficient way than plain JDBC + homemade utility classes, then there are two good options to consider:

- [ORM tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279613/what-is-an-orm-and-where-can-i-learn-more-about-it) (eg. JPA): these tools will let you map your existing tables to objects you create, then give you an awful lot of functionalities that will be available out-of-the-box. It does come free of course, you need to learn how to configure and use these, but after that it will become a very powerful tool.
- [General persistence framework](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/mybatis-tutorial-crud-operations-and-mapping-relationships-part-1.html) (eg. MyBatis): these are somehow easier to use (at least MyBatis is), with less functionality. I suggest reading the example and compare it to JPA to see which one suits you best.