# Return data from joined table in Knex update

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I have this `knex` update:

```
update = async (noteId, text, db) => (
    db.knex('notes')
      .returning([
        'id',
        'note',
        'user_id',
        'product_id',
        'timestamp',
      ])
      .where('id', noteId)
      .update({
        timestamp: new Date(),
        note: text,
      })
  );
```

In the returned data I wish to include `product_name`. This has to come from a product table which is joined on `notes.product_id = product.id`. How do I do this through `knex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knex is a SQL query builder. It's not an [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1279678/1913185). If you're looking for eager loading, you should check out an ORM like [ObjectionJS](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/).

To do this with Knex, you would do it the same as you do in SQL. The simplest way is to perform the update. Then, you'll need to perform a select and [knex's inner join](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-innerJoin).

```
update = async (noteId, text, db) => (
    await db.knex('notes')
      .where('id', noteId)
      .update({
        timestamp: new Date(),
        note: text,
      });

    const response = await db.knex('notes')
      .where('id', noteId)
      .innerJoin('products', 'notes.product_id', 'products.id')
      .first();

    return response;
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, however when I run that I get this error

`TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable`

Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: Try to remove `.first()`?

Comment: Perfect. That's exacxtly what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is using `returning('*')` like below code

```js
update = async (noteId, text, db) => {
  const result = await db
    .knex("notes")
    .where("id", noteId)
    .update({
      timestamp: new Date(),
      note: text,
    })
    .returning("*");
    return result?.length ? result[0] : null;
};
```

Thanks and Hope that help you