# I've created the table "person.db " but i can't see my database saved in sqlite

Tags: android-studio-3.0

public class DatabaseListView extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private Context context;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "person.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


private static final String TABlE_NAME = "person";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_Id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
private static final String COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE = "Birth_Date";
private static final String COLUMN_GENDER = "Gender";
private static final String COLUMN_INTERESTS = "Interests";
private static final String COLUMN_CHINESE_LEVEL = "Chinese_Level";
private static final String COLUMN_SELF_INTRO = "Self_Introduction";


public DatabaseListView(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
   String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABlE_NAME +
            "  (" + COLUMN_ID + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
           COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_INTERESTS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_CHINESE_LEVEL + " DOUBLE, " +
            COLUMN_SELF_INTRO + " TEXT)";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);
}

public void saveInfo(String personName, String personBirth, String personGender, String personInterests,
                     double chineseLevel, String selfIntro) {

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, personName);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE, personBirth);
    cv.put(COLUMN_GENDER, personGender);
    cv.put(COLUMN_INTERESTS, personInterests);
    cv.put(COLUMN_CHINESE_LEVEL, chineseLevel);
    cv.put(COLUMN_SELF_INTRO, selfIntro);

    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABlE_NAME, null, cv);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABlE_NAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
```

}

This Question is about Android Studio Person Manager project I've created the table "person.db " but i can't see my database saved in sqlite browser all i see is an empty table but no data information.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) from google.
When working with Databases i suggest using a [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279613/what-is-an-orm-how-does-it-work-and-how-should-i-use-one). I "automatically" creates your tables, manage your relationships and insert data in an efficent way