# Is there a way to back up only the structure without data when backing up mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

When backing up mongodb, I want to back up only the collection information about the database. Is there a way?

I am asking if there is a way to back up only the colllection without data using mongodump.

Comment: MongoDB is a schema-less database, thus there is nothing you could backup.

Comment: Yes I read your comment and changed the content of the question

Comment: are you running in some sort of storage capacity problems?

Comment: What do you mean by "collection information"? Maybe you just want to save the output of `db.getCollectionInfos()`

Comment: I believe I have answered your question. Can you check, unvote and accept it if it meets your requirements, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been noted that MongoDB is and remains schema-less, so unless you use [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/) or another [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279613/what-is-an-orm-how-does-it-work-and-how-should-i-use-one), is it difficult to get the schema directly from the data.

That being said, there is a tool called [mongodb-schema](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-schema) that can read your documents and INFER a schema from them. It creates a probability metric for each of the potential fields and also the assigned type. It may be useful if you want to retrospectively analyse the collections without resorting to a dump and manual inspection.

You can also use [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/schema/) to analyse your schemas. This is, again, based on the sampling of your data.

I believe this is the desired output, but for more clarity in your use case, please update the question accordingly.