# Use a variable as as key of an interface to get the typeof

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Is it possible to use a variable to get the typeof a key in a interface?

For example:

```
interface DbSchema {
  jobs: {
    jobId: number;
    jobName: string;
  }
  users: {
    userId: number;
    userName: string;
  }
}

// I know we can do this:
type JobsType = DbSchema["jobs"];

// Is there a way to do this:
const str = "jobs";
type JobsType = DbSchema[str];
```

Comment: I don’t think so since interfaces exist only at compile-time, but I’d love for someone with more TypeScript experience to chime in. Having said that, I smell an XY problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Of course, didn't think of compile-time. I think I overthinked it. I am trying to accomplish a interface for a whole database schema and later in my code get a subscheme of a table. But I think I have to take another approach :) Thnx.

Comment: It's not possible because of [Type Erasure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types). From your comment static typing is not what you are looking for. Instead look into an [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279613/what-is-an-orm-how-does-it-work-and-how-should-i-use-one) solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface DbSchema {
  jobs: {
    jobId: number;
    jobName: string;
  }
  users: {
    userId: number;
    userName: string;
  }
}

const str = "jobs";
type JobsType = DbSchema[typeof str];
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBEBGBlJALKAWwVQG9hVUArAe0wGcAuMiy6ugSQBNmwBXQplgBuVpVqYAcgkJRm9CDHABzUZQC+rPvVhMWbVNtjdeAoTDVsjMabPmKVlzZuBIaYBagUxUAXlQARBL0AaIQAJ4ADmgAUnT0ACpRaP5YuATEANoR0TRwXooAuqIA9CUGAHoA-EA)

const already narrow the type for you, you just need `typeof`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, using `keyof` and `typeof` keywords like this:

```
const s:keyof DbSchema = "jobs"
type JobsType = DbSchema[typeof s];
```

You should guarantee that type of `s` is `keyof DbSchema` and also when you want to get the type of one of the `DbSchema` properties you have to use `typeof s`.

---

But I think the more reasonable and cleaner approach is using a generic type. You can define a type like this :

```
type DbSchemaPropertyType<T extends keyof DbSchema> = DbSchema[T];
```

And use it easily :

```
const job:DbSchemaPropertyType<"jobs"> = {
    jobId: 1,
    jobName: "student"
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use `const str: keyof DbSchema = "jobs"`.  This will broaden the type of `str` from `"jobs"` to the union `"jobs" | "users"`.  You get stronger typing without it.  With `const str = "jobs"` the type of `str` is the literal string `"jobs"`, as it is a `const` and cannot be re-assigned.

Comment: You are right, it is possible to use `const str = "jobs"`. By means of inference the type of `str` will be `"jobs"`. But also when we do it like this `const str: keyof DbSchema = "jobs"` and after that, define another const like this : `const n = s;` , `n` type will be infered as `"job"` not `"jobs" | "users"`.