# Deleting is not supported in my data source? How can i activate that?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I just got this message from Visual Studio 2005, when I clicked on the delete command I added to my gridview using the interface for configuring the grid:

> Deleting is not supported by data
>   source 'transactionsSqlDataSource'
>   unless DeleteCommand is specified.

How can I activate that? I want my user to be able to delete a row when they click on the button Delete.

I already changed the property DeleteCommandType of my SQLDataSource to StoredProcedure.
What else do I need to do?

**UPDATE**

This is what I did, but I am missing something, I can't compile:

This is what I did at .cs:

```
public string DeleteCommand { get; set; }
```

How can I fix that, it says that the get is missing the body. I am not use to ASP.NET. Could you help me fixing this part of my code?

This is what I did at .aspx:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="transactionsSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:membershipsDBConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [brukerId], [kjoptekvoten], [pengeneutbetalt], [fyringsolje], [biltype], [kjoptid] FROM [Informasjon]" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Informasjon] WHERE fyringsolje='Kull: 2,42 kg';">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is the configuration for the datasource correct? Dont worry if you see that the delete command does not use parameters like the one above, it is just for a homework(I only need the query to pass).

**UPDATE 2**
I keep trying but i cant fix it. I am really newbie in ASP.NET and I am not very familiar with all the terminology. What exactly is happening here? How can I know the name of my store procedure?:

CS:

```
public string DeleteCommand { get { return DeleteCommand; } set { DeleteCommand = "";}
```

Aspx:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:membershipsDBConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [kjoptekvoten], [pengeneutbetalt], [fyringsolje], [biltype], [kjoptid] FROM [Informasjon]"
        DeleteCommand="StoredProcedureName">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When I click on Delete that row needs to be erased from table **Informasjon**
[image: Screenshot of GridView]

Comment: Have you set the DeleteCommand, as it tells you to? =)

Comment: Specify the Storedprocedure it has to execute(on deleting)?

Comment: @J. Steen You mean Delete Query?

Comment: @Mythje I don't understand, how i do that?

Comment: No, I mean DeleteCommand, as Crypth answers below. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.deletecommand.aspx

Comment: You can do all that in the sql configure data source wizard to if you prefer : http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-vb

Comment: I tried something, but i still stuck. Could you have a look at my update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either call a stored procedure if you have created one like below :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    // in the select command or your case delete you just input the name instead of a query
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Column1]=@Parameter1 AND [Column2]=@Parameter2 AND [Column3]=@Parameter3;" 
    DeleteCommand="StoredProcedureName"
    // Then ofcourse put the commandtype on storedprocedure but you already have that
    DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    // And you can declare the parameters like below
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Parameter1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Parameter2" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Parameter3" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Parameter4" Type="Boolean" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="Parameter1" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

For more information about storedprocedures please read : [What is a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459457/what-is-a-stored-procedure) 
Or you can directly call a query like in the example below :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [informasjon];"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [informasjon] WHERE [id]=@id;">
    <DeleteParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The connection string is something you will have to provide for yourself. For more info on the connectionstring please read : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry but i still confused.  this is how my code currently looks like:

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="transactionsSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:membershipsDBConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [brukerId], [kjoptekvoten], [pengeneutbetalt], [fyringsolje], [biltype], [kjoptid] FROM [Informasjon]" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" OnSelecting="transactionsSqlDataSource_Selecting">
        
    </asp:SqlDataSource>` I need to do something similar tho what you said, but just for deleting. But how?

Comment: If you add the tag DeleteCommand="StoredProcedureName" It will use the specified storedprodedure. And all the parameters that your stored procedure needs should aslo be added like i did in the example above

Comment: I don't know what is the name of my StoreProcedure. Where can i check that? i don't find that anywhere.

Comment: If you make your stored procedure in sql you will have to give it a name well that is the name you can also find the name in the sql server(manager) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: But are you really sure you want to use a stored procedure?

Comment: I am not sure, i think i dont know what the storeProcedureIs. I am really noob in ASP.NET and my homework says that i need to delete the row when i click on the button. How do you think i should do this in the easiest way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You do have to use a sql server? It is probably easier without stored procedure if you look at my example i made the select statement a normal statement instead of a stored procedure.

Comment: So i need to write the delete query where it says Delete Command? SOmething like this?:

`DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Informasjon] WHERE id=selected row">`

Could you please help me complete this query?

Comment: Yea something like that. If you look at my example i added a new piece of code that will be allot like what you need. Also i think you use it with a gridview? you have bound the sqldatasource to the gridview? Like this? DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" inside the gridview tag

Comment: You should do some research on what a stored procedure is and not wait on the professor to teach you.

Answer (score 5):

```
DeleteCommand="<your stored proc>"
```

is needed in your SqlDataSource along with any parameters you want, for instance:

```
<DeleteParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="myParameter" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
```

which needs to be added in the SqlDatasource tag.

Comment: What is missing? Do i need to have does parametters? can i make it work with out them? See update.

Comment: No there is no need to use parameters unless you want them and there's no need for a DeleteCommand string in your .cs file. What is the compiler error?