# How write two update queries using join condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `1->CompanyMaster_tbl` in this having Two fields . `Cid and CompanyName`,

> Cid is the primary key of this table

2->`DepartmentMaster_tbl` in this having 4 fields. `dtid,dtname,dtphon,dtmail,Cid`.

> dtid is the primary key,and Cid is the foreign key

I have two update query like this:

```
UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl SET CompanyName = @CompanyName WHERE Cid = @Cid

update DepartmentMaster_tbl set dtName = @dtName,dtPhone = @dtPhone,dtEmail = @dtEmail  where dtId=@dtid
```

is there any way to write this two query in single line with any of our join condition

Comment: I dont think you can update 2 seperate tables. look at answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2044520/1692632

Comment: Please clarify how you would like to join the tables. In the example, you have two variables, \@Cid and \@dtid, which are used to determine records to be updated. If those variables are not connected, the records are not connected either, which excludes using a JOIN. However, if those variables are connected, pls explain that, so that we know what is to be joined.

Comment: i cant update 2 separate tables together in sql server

Comment: can you create a meaningful view with both tables?

Comment: Cid is primary key in CompanyMaster_tbl and Cid is foreign key in DepartmentMaster_tbl and dtid is the primary key DepartmentMaster_tbl

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by

> is there any way to write this two query in single line **with any of our join condition**

but the code looks fine to me.
If you add some more information about what is bothering you with your existing code, or what you are trying to accomplish, I will modify this answer...

**Edit:**  (As per @user3106114 comment)
You can do both quesries in 1 line if you wrap them in a [Stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459457/what-is-a-stored-procedure).

Comment: in above i wrote two separate query,,i want to write that as a single qeury,,

Comment: @user3106114 What is your `Join condition`?

Comment: i can write somthing like this: UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl SET CompanyName = 'IBS' , d.dtName='ss' from CompanyMaster_tbl c join DepartmentMaster_tbl d
 on c.Cid= d.cId where c.Cid = 3 and d.dtId= 2

Comment: As @Darka pointed out, it is not possible to update 2 tables in a single row. You can wrap them up in a Stored procedure, or make sure they both are executed or rolled back upon failure using a transaction.