# What is wrong with the syntax of this MySQL query on dates?

Tags: mysql

phpMyAdmin tells me that the following code snippet is syntactically incorrect :

```
 SET @time := NOW();
 SET @timeset :=0;


 IF @timeset=1 
    THEN SET @time := DATE_ADD(@time,INTERVAL 10 SECOND);
    ELSE SET @time := DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
         SET @timeset := 1; 
    END IF;
```

but I fail to see what's wrong with it.

The exact error message goes : [image]

UPDATE : thanks to wolfgangalther's answer, I found the following workaround :

```
SET @time := NOW();
SET @timeset :=0;
SET @time=IF(@timeset=1,DATE_ADD(@time,INTERVAL 10 SECOND),DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)); 
SET @timeset:=1;
```

Comment: Are `timeset` and `time` declared?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I already thought of that. So yes, they are declared ; I just enlarged my code snippet to show that

Comment: As per your most recent question, we prefer code and error messages to be supplied as text. The code is fine here, but the error is a screenshot. Just copy it from your browser to the clipboard, and post it into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flow-control-statements.html):

> MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control **within stored programs**.

You are not allowed to issue an `IF` construct on its own!

There is also a short discussion about it here (including some alternatives):
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80132/using-if-statement-outside-of-a-stored-procedure-or-function

*Note: Using an IF statement at that place [has been requested as a feature in the past](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48777), but is not implemented into MySQL as of now.*

**Edit:**
Stored programs are either stored procedures or stored functions. Stored functions are the same thing as stored procedures, they just return a value.

Read more about stored procedures:

- Stackoverflow: [What is a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459457/what-is-a-stored-procedure)
- Tutorial: [An Introduction to Stored Procedures in MySQL 5](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843)
- MySQL manual: [Stored Programs and Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-views.html)

Comment: I apologize for my newbie ignorance, I do not know what a "stored program/function" is in this context ?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of `IF ELSE` you can only use in stored procedures, But you can use If condition in query as given below.
`IF(expr,if_true_expr,if_false_expr)`

Example

```
SELECT customerNumber,
       customerName,
       IF(state IS NULL,'N/A',state) state,
       country
FROM customers;
```