# Why do we need to use stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I had seen the features of it. But couldn't get the reason why to use

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459457/what-is-a-stored-procedure) link explains what it is and what benefit (if any) it has.

Answer (score 7):

We need to use the stored procedures by the following reasons.

**1. Reusable Execution plan**

Rather than the query, SP makes a cache of the Execution plan while saving it which can be reused

**2. Sharing**

Stored procedure can be shared among the different applications over the queries that used within the code.

**3. Protection over Sql Injection**

Sp provides security over injection attacks by using the checks rather than the query

**4. One place change**

It provides with a benefit to change in one place that reflect changes wherever it is used.

**5. Executing permissions**

SP has a feature where we can give the executing permission only to a user or role

Comment: The link provides [USES](http://stackoverflow.com/a/209040/7609073)

Answer (score -1):

Stored procedure is a set of SQL statements with an assigned name that's stored in the database in compiled form so that it can be shared by a number of programs.We can easily use the stored procedure whenever needed