# Writing a blog forum... and need help on sql

Tags: php, mysql

This sql function works on all my scripts except this one. Does anyone see what's wrong with it? The part that isn't working... is the part where it's supposed to insert the variable into a table. The include is for logging in the database, and that's all correct(I double checked).

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'dbh.php';

$confirm = $_POST['confirm'];
$check = $_SESSION['forum_name'];


if ($confirm == $check) {
  include_once 'dbh.php';

  $sql = "INSERT INTO forum_names (name) VALUES ('$forum_name');";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  header("Location: ../redir.php?postsuccess=success");

} else {
  echo "Your names do not match" . " ";
  echo "<a href='../redir.php'>Click here to try again</a>";
}
```

?>

Comment: Well, you never defined the variable `$forum_name`.  More specifically, what exactly do you expect this to do and what is it actually doing?  That is, how *specifically* is it failing?

Comment: In addition, though perhaps not an exact fix, you should look into using prepared statements in your PHP code.

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/). For the love of all that's holy, do NOT release this software until you've learned to use prepared statements.

Comment: Brace yourself, `Use Prepared Statements because your Script isn't secure` comments incoming.

Comment: SQL INJECTION ALERT, see above comment ^

Comment: refer this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459457/what-is-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

`$forum_name` doesn't exist. Therefore, either replace it with `$check`, or replace `$check` with `$forum_name`.

I have zero idea how this could possibly work on other pages using that code.

Comment: I had just realized that. Thanks