# Which table PreparedStatement queries from in java?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, prepared-statement

I recently came across `PreparedStatement` and I am a bit confused with it,Which table actually it queries the data from?

For example:

```
PreparedStatement state = con.prepareStatement("Select generate_id(?)");
state.setString(1, "SOME_TABLE");
ResultSet results = state.executeQuery();
```

So,whats the table name and whats the column name here? Can someone explain?

Thanks!

Comment: It's called a [stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459531/2970947). It invokes a function that is **stored** on the database.

Comment: Since nobody here knows what `generate_id` is, nobody can answer that.

Comment: is generate id a function or is there any query of this format?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution,Its a stored procedure.I can check the function details using:

```
SELECT prosrc FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'generate_id';
```